# Is there a list of forbidden subgraphs for comparability graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

The "graph classes: a survey" mentioned Trotter and other authors have presented a list of forbidden subgraph of comparability graph. But the google book( where I read graph classes: a survey) do not have the page which contains the reference of specific literature.
To my knowledge, one forbidden graph is "a k-cycle ( k is an odd intege $\ge$ 5) and no triangle chord".

Thank you for your help in advance. :-)

Answer (score 9):

You could refer to the entry for comparability graphs on graphclasses.org: http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_72.html
(look at "equivalent classes" and note that the list is not finite)

Comment: Although Stefan is right, the infinite part is simply "odd-hole-free".  The list also has helpful links to pictures of all the other excluded graphs.

Comment: No, András, every one of those "n"s in the exponents of many of the forbidden configurations are arbitrary parameters ... each one of those XF^ symbols is an infinite family of graphs. Also, the subscript $n$ for co-holes is another infinite set of forbidden graphs. It's not only the odd holes.

Answer (score 4):

You must be referring to page 91 of that book. The reference is T. GALLAI, Transitiv orientierbare Graphen, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hung., 18 (1967), 25-66. A translation exists, but I was unable to find it online.

The list is apparently also available in W.T. TROTTER, JR., Combinatorics and Partially Ordered Sets — Dimension Theory, Johns Hopkins University Press, Baltimore, London (1992).

Comment: The translation can be obtained from F. Maffray by an email request, that's how I got it myself. Be warned that the paper is a difficult read though (44p long, a number that doesn't bode well to me..)

Comment: The translation of Gallai's paper by Frederic Maffray and Myriam Preissmann is Chapter 3 of *Perfect Graphs* by Jorge L. Ramirez Alfonsin and Bruce A. Reed (eds.), Wiley, 2001, pages 25-66.

Comment: The list in Trotter's book is wrong. You can get the forbidden subgraphs by combining "TAFEL I" and "TAFEL II" in Gallai's paper, except that TAFEL I shows the *knotting graphs* of the graphs of interest (so you should merge the vertices that are drawn close together to get the actual graph) and TAFEL II contains the *complements* of the graphs of interest. Trotter forgot to complement the graphs in TAFEL II.